# 'ListSerializer' when serializing a queryset using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a slightly complicated APIView which makes that I can't use a generic [ListAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) to return a queryset. But I can't seem to simply serialize a simple Django queryset using a ModelSerializer, even when I set `many=True`.

Somehow this doesn't work:

**serializers.py:**

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['some_field']
```

**views.py:**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class SomeAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = SomeInputSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # first some business logic, then return results
            results = SomeModel.objects.all()
            output_serializer = SomeModelSerializer(results, many=True)
            return Response(output_serializer.data)
```

All I keep getting is: `'ListSerializer' object is not iterable`.

What am I doing wrong?

Error:

```
/projectfolder/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render
            try:
                values = self.sequence.resolve(context, True)
            except VariableDoesNotExist:
                values = []
            if values is None:
                values = []
            if not hasattr(values, '__len__'):
                values = list(values) ...
            len_values = len(values)
            if len_values < 1:
                return self.nodelist_empty.render(context)
            nodelist = []
            if self.is_reversed:
                values = reversed(values)
```

`values = list(values)` seems to be responsible for the error

Comment: This code looks fine. Could you provide more of your actual code? Which line throws the error?

Comment: @ilse2005 The last one. I can actually print output_serializer.data to the console with no problems, but get the error when returning the Response object. I've included an error log.

Comment: From where do you import Response?

Comment: @ilse2005 `rest_framework.response`, updated the example

Answer (score 7):

Was running into the same problem as you did. I found a quick and simple fix for the error: Copy the serializer data to a new array and return that.

```
results = SomeModel.objects.all()

output_serializer = SomeModelSerializer(results, many=True)    
data = output_serializer.data[:]

return Response(data)
```

This works for me, hopefully for you as well.

Answer (score 6):

Below works for me using an as_view() url:

```
 class ListCreateMemberViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        """
        API endpoint that allows multiple members to be created.
        """
        queryset = Member.objects.none()
        serializer_class = MemberSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = Member.objects.all()
         return queryset

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list))
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        results = Member.objects.all()
        output_serializer = MemberSerializer(results, many=True)
        data = output_serializer.data[:]
        return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is a result of trying to run a `list`  on a serializer directly.

For example, this would raise the above exception:

```
results = Member.objects.all()
output_serializer = MemberSerializer(results, many=True)
all_results = list(output_serializer) # this line here
all_results += output_serializer  # or this line here
```

And this would not (difference is that we are listing `output_serializer.data` instead of `output_serializer`):

```
results = Member.objects.all()
output_serializer = MemberSerializer(results, many=True)
all_results = list(output_serializer.data)
all_results += output_serializer.data
```

I have the feeling that in the original question, the example code was not 100% matching the actual code.