# serializer call is showing an TypeError: Object of type 'ListSerializer' is not JSON serializable?

Tags: python, django

Iam trying to call a serializer in django GET request But it shows up an
TypeError: Object of type 'ListSerializer' is not JSON serializable
Please help me if i went wrong somewhere. Thanks in Advance.

```py
class Member(MemberMixin, APIView):

    serializer_class = MemberSerializers

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        objects = MemberSerializers(Members.objects.all(), many=True)
        self.meta_data = "GET"
        self.module = "Member"
        self.data = objects
        if objects is None:
            self.error = "datas are not found"
            return Response(self.response_obj, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            return Response(self.response_obj, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        pass
```

The serializer code is as follows:

```py
from .models import Members


class MemberSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Members
        fields = ('username', 'fullname', 'phone','address','memberid')
        # exclude = ['']
    pass
```

MemberMixins code as follows:

```py
class MemberMixin(object):
    meta_data = dict()
    data = dict()
    error = dict()

    def __init__(self):
        self.meta_data = dict()
        self.data = dict()
        self.error = dict()
        self.json_schema = None
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def response_obj(self):
        resp = dict()
        resp['meta'] = self.meta_data
        if self.error:
            resp['error'] = self.error
        else:
            resp['data'] = {
                'detail': self.data,
            }
        return resp

    pass
```

Comment: please upload your error message and serializer

Comment: Have a look there: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577692/listserializer-when-serializing-a-queryset-using-django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577692/listserializer-when-serializing-a-queryset-using-django-rest-framework)

Comment: This isn't your real code: `self.response_obj` is not defined. And what's the point of setting all those attributes that you never use? Please show your actual code and the full traceback.

Comment: @Daniel self.response_obj is called from MemberMixin

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending the serializer itself, rather than the serialized data, to the response. You should change it to:

```
self.data = objects.data
```

But that said, most of this code is totally unnecessary, You're bypassing most of .he things that Django and DRF do for you already. Remove your mixin and use a ListAPIView.